# Serialize deserialize from Go int64/uint64 from/to Javascript string

Tags: javascript, json, go, json-deserialization, json-serialization

Is it possible to modify json serialization and deserialization so that a struct like this:

```
type Foo struct {
   A int64
   B uint64
   // and other stuff with int64 and uint64 and there's a lot of struct that are like this
}

x := Foo{A: 1234567890987654, B: 987654321012345678}
byt, err := json.Marshal(x)
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Println(string(byt))

//                                 9223372036854775808      9223372036854775808
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"A":"12345678901234567", "B":"98765432101234567"}`), &x)
// ^ must be quoted since javascript can't represent those values properly (2^53)
// ^ json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Foo.A of type int64
fmt.Println(err)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", x)
// main.Foo{A:1234567890987654, B:0xdb4da5f44d20b4e}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dHN-FcJ7p-N

So that It could receive json string but parsed as int64/uint64, and can deserialize int64/uint64 as json string without have to modify the struct or struct tag at all

Comment: "without have to modify the struct or struct tag at all" no. The struct and struct tags are what determine how it is marshaled and unmarshaled.

Comment: You could however write a custom unmarshaling method with an anonymous struct and parse the strings to int64/uint64 locally.

Comment: Javascript often outputs inconsistent data as json.  A more catch-all approach would be to unmarshall in `interface{}` type and then use a type switch... if it is detected as string you cast it to string and then use `strings.ParseInt()` if it isn't then you can take another route.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`string` option](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) in the JSON struct tag. It's designed exactly for this use case:

> The "string" option signals that a field is stored as JSON inside a JSON-encoded string. It applies only to fields of string, floating point, integer, or boolean types. This extra level of encoding is sometimes *used when communicating with JavaScript programs*

```
type Foo struct {
    A int64  `json:"A,string"`
    B uint64 `json:"B,string"`
}

func main() {
    x := &Foo{}
    _ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{"A":"12345678901234567", "B":"98765432101234567"}`), x)

    fmt.Println(x) // &{12345678901234567 98765432101234567}

    b, _ := json.Marshal(x)

    fmt.Println(string(b)) // {"A":"12345678901234567","B":"98765432101234567"}
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/IfpcYOlcKMo

If you can't modify existing struct tags (but your example has none), then you have to reinvent the implementation of this `string` tag option in a custom `UnmarshalJSON` and `MarshalJSON`  methods.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new. This answer is simple and effective

Comment: ah too bad with string tag cannot parse plain integer https://play.golang.org/p/LIyt9ZdHPeg

Comment: @Kokizzu I think that is expected. With these standard tags, you either deserialize JSON strings to integers or JSON numbers to integers. If you need a deserializer that does both, you have to implement it yourself